# Closing laptop lid suspends Lubuntu, since upgrade

Tags: 13.10, lubuntu, power-management

I recently upgraded my Lubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10.

I have my `xfce-power-manager` set on the lock screen action on lid close, but closing the lid still suspends the laptop in 13.10.

How can I set it to lock the screen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a confirmed bug.

This trick work for me (Lubuntu 13.10):

Set "HandleLidSwitch=ignore" in "/etc/systemd/logind.conf" and restart.

source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1222021

Answer (score 0):

I have also had this problem since upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10. I run an external monitor on my laptop, and like to have the lid closed while I work. I tried editing logind.conf however - I had no success.

In terminal type `dconf-editor`to and then open up the menus on the left by clicking ->org -> gnome -> settings daemon -> plugins -> power

There us an option there called 'lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor'

This did the trick for me!