# Lubuntu 14.04: how to avoid lock screen on closing laptop lid?

Tags: lubuntu, laptop, xfce, lock-screen, lid

I upgraded my OS from Lubuntu 13.10 to Lubuntu 14.04 a few days ago, and now my screen locks when the lid is closed, while I want nothing to happen when lid is closed.

I have already set the right option in the Xfce power manager ("When laptop lid is closed: *Nothing*") and, as of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1307545 and [Closing laptop lid suspends Lubuntu, since upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363795/closing-laptop-lid-suspends-lubuntu-since-upgrade) , I tried editing `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`; but when I close the lid, the screen still locks and asks for a password. Note that this doesn't happen every time I close the screen; sometimes it stay closed for a few minutes and can be reopened without having been locked, and sometimes it locks as soon as I close the lid.

For reference, here's the content of my `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`:

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details

[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#Controllers=
#ResetControllers=cpu
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
```

Is there's something wrong with what I'm doing? What can I do to be able to close the lid without anything happening?

EDIT: Possible pointers would be about what exactly happens when I close my lid; I tried investigating in that direction, but I don't know where to start. If a script or something is called on lid closing, I might even be content with modifying it to do nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track with `logind.conf`, but you only need to change this line from the default configuration:

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

(i.e. you don't need `LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no`).

In addition, you need to configure `xfce4-power-manager` to handle the lid switch. I found that the reliable way was to Quit it from the power manager icon menu before configuring it with

```
$ xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/logind-handle-lid-switch -s true
```

You'll then need to restart (unless there's another way to get `logind` to pick up its configuration, in which case I'd love to hear it!).

After this, the lid switch should operate according to the settings in the power manager.

I found this solution thanks to [a comment on a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1349056/comments/5) linked by a helpful person in #xubuntu.

Note that this [breaks screen locking on suspend](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xdg-utils/+bug/1366153).

Comment: as for getting logind to read its config: $ restart systemd-logind

Comment: This is the right answer. I can't believe there is no other way to accomplish this in Xubuntu.

Comment: Since 15.04, `sudo service systemd-logind restart` to reload `logind` configuration. See http://askubuntu.com/a/372616

Comment: Do **NOT** modify `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` directly, as it will be eventually overwritten by an update (happened to me the other day). Create a `*.conf` file under `/etc/systemd/logind.conf.d` instead (see man `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`).

Answer (score 1):

I solved uninstalling xfce4-power-manager and rebooting. It could work because systemd and xfce4-power-manager are in conflict

Comment: It works, but I'd prefer to keep xfce4-power-manager... I'm going to see if I can look in the matter a little further, otherwise yours is the best solution as far as I can see

Answer (score 0):

sudo /etc/UPower/UPower.conf

change: ignorelid=false to ignorelid=true

ctrl o (save/write)
crlt W (exit

no need for reboot-should work right away.

Not sure what all that other stuff is...complicated for sure...

Cheers